# Swift bezier curve fill gradient fill

Tags: ios, swift, uibezierpath

Trying to create this curve in Swift using CG drawing on a view in my storyboard.
I've done the white curve but having trouble with filling it with a gradient as show in the image
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are three parts to this image.

1. The white curve.
2. The gradient.
3. The mask that blocks out the gradient.

Your best approach would be to create these as separate layers.

First create a CAGradientLayer with your desired colours.
Then create a path curve in white and add it above the gradient.

Now create a third layer with a closed path (similar to the curve but closed at the bottom. Use this as a maskLayer on the gradient layer.

Comment: I also wish to animate the graphic (the curve to shrink and expand accordingly), will your solution still work?

Comment: If you can animate a path then everything I have said will still work. Just animate the path of the curve and the mask at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

Here is working code

```
class FillCurve: UIView {


    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        // Drawing ARC

        let center = CGPoint(x: bounds.width /  2 , y: bounds.height / 2)
        let curve = UIBezierPath()
        curve.move(to:CGPoint(x: 10, y: bounds.height - 20))
        curve.addQuadCurve(to: CGPoint(x: bounds.width - 20 , y: bounds.height - 20), controlPoint:center )
        UIColor.white.setStroke()
        curve.lineWidth = 2.0

        curve.stroke()

        let fillPath = curve.copy() as! UIBezierPath

        fillPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: bounds.width , y: bounds.height - 2))
        fillPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: bounds.height - 2))

        fillPath.close()
        fillPath.fill()
        fillPath.addClip()

        let colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB()
        let colors = [UIColor.cyan.cgColor,UIColor.black.cgColor]
        let location:[CGFloat] = [0.0,1.0]
        let gradient = CGGradient(colorsSpace: colorSpace, colors: colors as CFArray, locations: location)!
        UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()?.drawLinearGradient(gradient, start: CGPoint(x: 0, y: fillPath.bounds.height), end: CGPoint(x: 0, y: bounds.height), options: [])

    }


}
```

output

[image]